# Alternative to IRS Online Transcript (for W2, Paystub)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding, form-w-2, record-keeping

I am trying to get IRS online transcript to obtain needed info for my W2 and paystub for most recent period (year). However, for me it doesn't seem possible to get that classical online transcript.

So far I am already aware of two alternative options: whether I should ask my employer, or request the information by mail.

Therefore would like to particularly emphasize that I am looking for ONLINE alternative. Already tried to call but I was told they can help me for federal info only but not for state. Having said that, this is not sufficient for both W2 and paystub.

Online transcript of any type would be sufficient but I am unable to register account. Would anyone please be so kind to tell me from where else ONLINE I could get all needed info that is on my W2 and paystub?

Comment: does your employer give you a paper copy of your pay stub and w2, or do they post the stub and w2 on their payroll site?

Comment: IRS (and state tax authorities) only get relevant parts of W2, and W2 doesn't necessarily contain everything on your paystub anyway, so for complete paystubs your employer (or their payroll service, if outsourced) is your _only_ source, and whether they choose to do it online is up to them.

Comment: mhoran No payroll site i am aware of. So paper copy only.

Dave I did not say W2 contains everything that Paystub does. What i asked is where, ONLINE ( ! ), besides classical transcript, could i get all information that is usually "located" on both W2 and Paystub for most recent year? I still have the data for 2015 year so EIN is available but not the rest of numerical values (all of them for both w2 and paystub).

Answer (score 2):

The pay stub info is only held by the employer/payroll company and the employee.

The W-2 information is only held by the employer/payroll company, the employee, and the tax authorities (federal, state and local).

There is information on the pay stub, that doesn't appear on the W-2: number of hours worked, PTO balance, matching 401K deposits, direct deposit information, and other deductions that aren't related to taxes.

Even though it is the night before taxes are due for 2018, it is likely that the IRS and other tax authorities don't have your 2018 W-2 numbers assigned to your accounts.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The solutions you listed won't work because they are not online solutions. I am trying to restore forgotten password for online transcript. I know username but the problem is that used email address is forgotten too. Tried to contacted I R S but they told me they don't have TECHNICAL support department who could change email address for me.